# Call JS function from Rails helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a helper function to add fields to `new_order` form with new address.

```
def link_to_add_address_fields(f, association)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render partial: 'orders/order_address_fields', locals: {a: builder}
  end

  content_tag :div, class: 'form-group add_new_address_links' do
    content_tag :div, class: 'row' do
      content_tag :div, class: 'col-lg-12' do
        link_to 'Add new address', 'javascript:void(0)', class: 'btn btn_new_address', data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub('\n', '')}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, when user click on `btn_new_address` link, new address fields from `orders/order_address_fields` partial appears in form.

This is `orders/order_address_fields` partial:

```
.form-group.new_order_address_fields
  .row
    .col-lg-10
      = a.text_field :street, class: 'form-control new_order_street'
      = a.text_field :building, class: 'form-control new_order_building'
      = a.text_field :entrance, class: 'form-control new_order_entrance'
      = link_to '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>'.html_safe, 'javascript:void(0)', class: 'btn btn-default remove_address'
    .col-lg-2.hidden-xs
      = link_to '<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>'.html_safe, 'javascript:void(0)', class: 'btn btn-default full-size find_me_on_map'
```

But there is a `find_me_on_map` link, which runs a JS function, when user clicks on it. This is a function from `orders.coffee`

```
jQuery.fn.clickOnFindMeOnMapButton = ->
  $(this).click ->
    street_field = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('input.new_order_street')
    building_field = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('input.new_order_building')
    findMeOnMap(street_field, building_field)

ready = ->

  $('a.find_me_on_map').clickOnFindMeOnMapButton()

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

It works on newly loaded page with one address field, but when I add another field, I need to apply this function to the `find_me_on_map` link from newly loaded address fields. And I don't know, how to do it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need live changes, in new jquery you can do it like this:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'a.find_me_on_map' ->
  # call function
```

Comment: Add comma after 'a.find_me_on_map'. I can't do it, because SO need 6 chars to edit the answer.